# Having multiple objects in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a couple of lists which I want to make into a dictionary. The powerlist is a list of tuples(8long) for 24 entries. placelist is a list with 8 entries.
Right now i'm only getting the first set of powerlist data in the dictionary.

```
        for i in self.powerlist:
            self.dictionary = {}
            self.dictionary = dict(zip(self.placelist, self.powerlist))
```

I want the dictionary to display like this:

```
Placelist1: (powerlistuple1, powerlist tuple9, powerlist tuple17),
placelist2: (powerlisttupe2, powerlist tuple10, powerlist tuple 18), etc etc
```

How do I do this? I have tried running the above code with `self.powerlist(i)` but it gives me a type error. How would I do this?

```
powerlist[0]
[(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17, 34, 51), ...for 24]

placelist[0]
["A place", "A different place", ..etc for 8]
```

Comment: To remove ambiguity, please show an example each of `powerlist` and `placelist`.

Comment: You keep setting `self.dictionary` equal to the same thing and don't use `i` in your loop at all

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, yes i know-I have just been playing around with things so it's not doing anything at the moment because it gives me an error if I put it where I think it is, I'm really just looking the iterable over the dictionary 'values' congurent to the correct key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You keep setting `self.dictionary` to the same thing over and over in your loop, you need something like:

```
  self.dictionary = {}  
  for ind,tup in enumerate(self.placelist):
        self.dictionary["Placelist{}".format(ind)] = (self.powerlist[:ind+8], tup)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.dictionary = {}
for ii, place in enumerate(self.placelist):
    self.dictionary[place] = (self.powerlist[ii],
            self.powerlist[ii + 8], self.powerlist[ii + 16])
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see a pattern here, you are adding 8 items every-time (i+8)*j

```
# generate an example 
l= [x for x in range(100)]

res= [[y for y in l if y%8==i] for i in range(8)]

print res
```

**Output:**

> res= [[0, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, 72, 80, 88, 96],   [1, 9,
>   17, 25, 33, 41, 49, 57, 65, 73,81, 89, 97],   [2, 10, 18, 26, 34,
>   42,50, 58, 66, 74, 82, 90, 98],   [3, 11, 19, 27, 35, 43, 51, 59, 67,
>   75, 83, 91, 99],  [4, 12, 20, 28, 36, 44, 52, 60, 68, 76, 84, 92], 
>   [5, 13, 21, 29, 37, 45, 53, 61, 69, 77, 85, 93],  [6, 14, 22, 30, 38,
>   46, 54, 62, 70, 78, 86, 94],  [7, 15, 23, 31, 39, 47, 55, 63, 71, 79,
>   87, 95]]